# transforming configMapKeyRef into secretKeyRef with jq

Tags: json, kubernetes, jq, kubernetes-secrets

Here is my deploy input

```json
{
  "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
  "kind": "Deployment",
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "io.kompose.service": "item-api"
      }
    },
    "strategy": {
      "type": "Recreate"
    },
    "template": {
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "env": [
              {
                "name": "APP_JWTSECRET",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "configMapKeyRef": {
                    "key": "APP_JWTSECRET",
                    "name": "item-api-env"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "SPRING_DATASOURCE_BASEXML_JDBCURL",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "configMapKeyRef": {
                    "key": "SPRING_DATASOURCE_BASEXML_JDBCURL",
                    "name": "item-api-env"
                  }
                }
              }
...
```

For each item into `env`, I'd like to transform the `configMapKeyRef` into `secretKeyRef`if name contains (SECRET|PASSWORD|KEY) pattern and then replace the secretKeyRef name by the key name into lowcase.

for example:

```json
                "name": "APP_JWTSECRET",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "configMapKeyRef": {
                    "key": "APP_JWTSECRET",
                    "name": "item-api-env"
                  }
                }
              }
```

would be transformed into

```json
                "name": "APP_JWTSECRET",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "secretKeyRef": {
                    "key": "APP_JWTSECRET",
                    "name": "app-jwtsecret"
                  }
                }
              }
```

I tried some kind of manipulation with `with_entries` without any success:

```
jq -r '.spec.template.spec.containers[].env[]|with_entries(.key |test(PASSWORD|SECRET))'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it.  The `containers` and `env` array are rewritten with the desired modification, or kept *"as is"* if the condition isn't met.

```jq
.spec.template.spec.containers
|= map(
    (.env
     |= map(
          if (.name|test("SECRET|PASSWORD|KEY"))
          then .valueFrom
            |= with_entries(.key="secretKeyRef"
                 |.value.name=(.value.key|ascii_downcase|gsub("_";"-"))
               )
          else .
          end
        )
    )? // .
)
```

Try it on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/nqtiSZplJga).

Answer (score 2):

- Navigate to the desired locations: `.spec.template.spec.containers[].env[]?`
- Filter for those matching your criteria: `select(.name | test("SECRET|PASSWORD|KEY"))`
- Take those results and go deeper: `(…).valueFrom`
- Update it with access to `.key` and `.value`: `|= with_entries(…)`
- Only if the key matches that name: `select(.key == "configMapKeyRef") |= …`
- By redefining key and value: `{key: "secretKeyRef", value: …}`
- The new value is based on the previous value, and assigns the lowercase key to name: `.value | .name = (.key | ascii_downcase)`

```bash
(
    .spec.template.spec.containers[].env[]?
    | select(.name | test("SECRET|PASSWORD|KEY"))
)

.valueFrom |= with_entries(select(.key == "configMapKeyRef") |= {
    key: "secretKeyRef", value: (.value | .name = (.key | ascii_downcase))
})
```

```json
{
  "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
  "kind": "Deployment",
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "io.kompose.service": "item-api"
      }
    },
    "strategy": {
      "type": "Recreate"
    },
    "template": {
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "env": [
              {
                "name": "APP_JWTSECRET",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "secretKeyRef": {
                    "key": "APP_JWTSECRET",
                    "name": "app_jwtsecret"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "SPRING_DATASOURCE_BASEXML_JDBCURL",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "configMapKeyRef": {
                    "key": "SPRING_DATASOURCE_BASEXML_JDBCURL",
                    "name": "item-api-env"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ZEOS0v0QDOU)

Note: I regarded the change from `app_jwtsecret` to `app-jwtsecret` a typo.

Comment: Will `containers` ever have a non-`"env"` element?  If so, [there's an issue](https://jqplay.org/s/DGRFSxSbVJH).

Comment: @rickhg12hs Well spotted, thank you. Adding the missing `?`…

Answer (score 1):

One way to use `jq` would be to do below.

```
.spec.template.spec.containers[].env[] |= {name} + 
if .name | test("SECRET|PASSWORD|KEY") then 
    .valueFrom |= ( 
        with_entries(
            if .key == "configMapKeyRef" then .key = "secretKeyRef" end | 
                .value |= {key} + {name: .key|ascii_downcase}
        )
    )
end
```

jqplay demo - https://jqplay.org/s/UfYQYpJIa6o

Comment: something goes wrong with ubuntu embedded jq 1.6, only works with 1.7
`jq: error: syntax error, unexpected end`

Comment: Yes that is change in jq-1.7, it now supports, `if` conditionals without an empty else statment, i.e. `else .` can be ignored - https://github.com/jqlang/jq/releases/tag/jq-1.7 @NathanaëlBlanchet